# Is plist a good way to hold 3 arrays with +/- 500 entries?

Tags: iphone, plist

I'm making history list to my app and want to use .plist with 3 arrays - picture name, date and some text data. 
Is plist good solution for this? I think max number of history entries will be +/- 500.

Comment: Yes plists are good if you have limited data otherwise if you have large data and want to save manipulation time then I recommend using Core Data

Comment: I think it's good enough. Consider using a binary plist if you're really concerned by performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `plist` is a good option.
But keep in mind that data is read from a `plist` file as whole. So, it might decrease performance.

And for saving history, if the pictureName, date and someText are related; can't you group them into a dictionary instead of using 3 different arrays ?

Like:

```
<entry>
<pictureName>Name of Picture</picture>
<date>date on picture</date>
<text>some text</text>
</entry>
```

Edit:

As mentioned in comments, you can look at `CoreData` also.
It is an elegant way to store/retrieve data.

[Here is a good tutorial to get started with](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) :)

Comment: Going off of your comment about the plist being read as a whole, CoreData might be the better solution in this case because I suspect entries might need to be loaded/modified individually.